# How to refer to complex job titles in cover letters?

Tags: punctuation, jobs, cover-letter

Sometimes job listings use slashes and hyphens in the title of the job to specify specialties or other job characteristics. For instance, here are two listings on stack exchange: [Data Scientist - Dynamic Pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/224524/data-scientist-m-f-x-dynamic-pricing-flixbus?so=i&pg=1&offset=12), [Data Scientist/Machine Learning Expert](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/208477/data-scientist-machine-learning-expert-agoda?so=i&pg=2&offset=13). The first line of my cover letter is usually something like "I'm writing to apply for position X at company Y". What is the best practice for referencing the job title in this sentence? Is it acceptable to quote the job title with hyphens or should I simplify to an essential title like "data scientist"?

Comment: From experience, the companies you are looking at love to hear all the words from this great reference list:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_buzzwords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do it exactly the same way the company does it.**

If you know what job to apply for, it's because you saw it in an ad, on their website, or in another listing.

**The hyphen and the slash are used differently.**

The hyphen means "this job is for a data scientist doing dynamic pricing."

The slash means "this job is a combination data scientist and machine learning expert."

It can be subtle and it may even be that many jobs can use either.  But they have that punctuation for a reason (probably), so keep it.

**Don't shorten it.**

Don't just say "data scientist" because they'll wonder which of the many data scientist jobs you meant.